# Node app fails to connect to MongoDB, but only in Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I have two apps:

- MongoDB (started from the [Bitnami MongoDB Docker image](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mongodb))
- My custom node app

The two apps interact flawlessly when my node app is run natively. Now I've put it inside a Docker container and when I start both together with `docker compose up`, the backend can not connect to MongoDB.

This is an excerpt of the startup sequence:

```
mongodb_1   | 2018-11-10T22:22:52.481+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
[...]
backend_1   | 2018-11-10T22:23:48.119Z 'MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]'
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:

  mongodb:
    image: bitnami/mongodb:latest
    expose:
      - 27017
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    environment:
      API_HOST: http://localhost:3000/
      APP_SERVER_PORT: 3000
    expose:
      - 3000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app/backend
    links:
      - mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

This is my node call to the DB:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/groceryList', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

I skimmed about 15 Stackoverflow questions asking the same and I am not getting the cause:

- It is not that MongoDB is not ready when my node app tries to
  connect. I wrapped my connection call into an auto reconnection
  function as described [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5169#issuecomment-314983113) and the error repeats endlessly. It is not just about the "first
  connect".
- I can publish Port 27017 of the MongoDB container and
  happily connect with [Robo3T](https://robomongo.org/download). The DB is definitely working.
- When I connect to `mongodb://mongo:27017/groceryList` instead, the same applies, only with the `ENOTFOUND` flag instead of `ECONNREFUSED`.

What am I missing?

- Docker 18.06.1-ce
- docker-compose 1.22.0
- Mongoose 5.3.6
- MongoDB 4.0.3
- Node 11.1.0
- macOS 10.14.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mongodb service is named `mongodb` not `mongo`.

Try

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongodb:27017/groceryList', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

The generic form is `'mongodb://mongoServiceName:27017/dbname'`, this uses docker's automatic dns resolution for containers within the same network.

And as you may already know from other questions/answers, within a container, the url is relative to itself, therefore since there not mongodb running inside the backend container, it can't connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use localhost:27017 into a container to communicate with other because the scope "localhost" is self refering (localhost:27017 will look for the port 27017 into the container **backend** - not in **mongodb** container)

Then, you ned to put or the service name (mongodb) or IP of your machine